# PlayN HTML wont work with playn-jbox2d

Tags: gwt, jbox2d, playn

Whenever I try and Compile my PlayN project with playn-jbox2D as a dependecy, I get the following error on HTML ONLY, the rest turns out ok

```
    [INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
    [INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createField(BuildTypeMap.java:570)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$300(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:180)
    [INFO]  at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration.traverse(FieldDeclaration.java:285)
    [INFO]  at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1343)
    [INFO]  at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1223)
    [INFO]  at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDec    laration.java:687)
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
        [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599        )
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    [INFO]  at     com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
    [INFO]       [ERROR] <no source info>: public class org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body
    [INFO]  extends java.lang.Object
    [INFO] /*   fields   */
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_islandFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_awakeFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_autoSleepFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_bulletFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_fixedRotationFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_activeFlag
    [INFO] public static final [unresolved] int e_toiFlag
    [INFO] public [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyType m_type
    [INFO] public [unresolved] int m_flags
    [INFO] public [unresolved] int m_islandIndex
    [INFO] public final [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.common.Transform m_xf
    [INFO] public final [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.common.Sweep m_sweep
    [INFO] public final [unresolved] org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 m_linearVelocity
    [INFO] public [unresolved] float m_angularVelocity
[INFO] public final [unresolved] org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 m_force
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_torque
[INFO] public [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.World m_world
[INFO] public [unresolved] org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body m_prev
[INFO] public [unresolved] org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body m_next
[INFO] public [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture m_fixtureList
[INFO] public [unresolved] int m_fixtureCount
[INFO] public [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.joints.JointEdge m_jointList
[INFO] public [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.ContactEdge m_contactList
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_mass
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_invMass
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_I
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_invI
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_linearDamping
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_angularDamping
[INFO] public [unresolved] float m_sleepTime
[INFO] public [unresolved] java.lang.Object m_userData
[INFO] private final [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.FixtureDef fixDef
[INFO] private final [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.MassData pmd
[INFO] private final [unresolved] Unresolved type org.jbox2d.common.Transform pxf
[INFO] static final [unresolved] boolean $assertionsDisabled
[INFO] /*   methods   */
[INFO] [unresolved] public void <init>(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyDef, Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.World) 
[INFO] [unresolved] protected final void advance(float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void applyAngularImpulse(float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void applyForce(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void applyLinearImpulse(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void applyTorque(float) 
[INFO] public final org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture createFixture(org.jbox2d.dynamics.FixtureDef) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture createFixture(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.Shape, float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void destroyFixture(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getAngle() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getAngularDamping() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getAngularVelocity() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.ContactEdge getContactList() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture getFixtureList() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getInertia() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.joints.JointEdge getJointList() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getLinearDamping() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLinearVelocity() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLinearVelocityFromLocalPoint(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getLinearVelocityFromLocalPointToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLinearVelocityFromWorldPoint(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getLinearVelocityFromWorldPointToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLocalCenter() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLocalPoint(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getLocalPointToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getLocalVector(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getLocalVectorToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final float getMass() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getMassData(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.MassData) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body getNext() 
[INFO] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getPosition() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.common.Transform getTransform() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyType getType() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final java.lang.Object getUserData() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.World getWorld() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getWorldCenter() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getWorldPoint(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getWorldPointToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final org.jbox2d.common.Vec2 getWorldVector(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void getWorldVectorToOut(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public boolean isActive() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public boolean isAwake() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final boolean isBullet() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public boolean isFixedRotation() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public boolean isSleepingAllowed() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void resetMassData() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void setActive(boolean) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setAngularDamping(float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setAngularVelocity(float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void setAwake(boolean) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setBullet(boolean) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void setFixedRotation(boolean) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setLinearDamping(float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setLinearVelocity(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setMassData(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.MassData) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void setSleepingAllowed(boolean) 
[INFO] public final void setTransform(org.jbox2d.common.Vec2, float) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void setType(Unresolved type org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyType) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void setUserData(java.lang.Object) 
[INFO] [unresolved] public boolean shouldCollide(org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body) 
[INFO] [unresolved] protected final void synchronizeFixtures() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public final void synchronizeTransform() 
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
[INFO]       [ERROR] at SpikeJumper.java(29): Body bdy;
[INFO]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this, I can find no help/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem was as well as adding playn-jbox2D to the core pom, I needed to seperatly add

```
<inherits name="org.jbox2d.GwtBox2D" />
```

To the ProjectName.gwt.xml